# How to do Rails migration involving Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-migrations

How do people write their Rails migrations that involve [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)? I feel that I might be missing something obvious as I have now written my own migration helpers hacks that makes it easier and also take care of doing necessary filesystem changes. And of course you should test run these kinds of migrations in a development (and staging) environment before deploying to production.

[Paperclip migration rename, add and remove helpers](https://gist.github.com/1232562)
[Paperclip change path migration helper](https://gist.github.com/1299311) (not really a database migration but think it fits quite nice anyway)

Are there any better solutions or best practices? some people seems to create rake tasks etc. which feels quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 38):

There are generators included in the gem for this:

Rails 2:

```
script/generate paperclip Class attachment1 (attachment2 ...)
```

Rails 3:

```
rails generate paperclip Class attachment1 (attachment2 ...)
```

e.g.

```
rails generate paperclip User avatar
```

generates:

```
class AddAttachmentsAvatarToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :avatar_file_name, :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_content_type, :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_file_size, :integer
    add_column :users, :avatar_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :avatar_file_name
    remove_column :users, :avatar_content_type
    remove_column :users, :avatar_file_size
    remove_column :users, :avatar_updated_at
  end
end
```

Also see the helper methods used in the example in the [readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.has_attached_file :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have been a bit more clear that I mostly meant migrations involving existing paperclip columns and doing rename and change of path which will need filesystem changes etc.

Comment: Ah, check out this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708115/paperclip-renaming-files-after-theyre-saved/6335337#6335337

Comment: Ok, That locka more or less as what i do in my helpers. Guess thats how people do it then.