# Force paperclip to rename files when custom interpolation change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I use Paperclip to manage uploaded images for a certain Model in Rails 3. This model `belongs_to` another model. I want my image path to reflect this relationship, so I created a custom interpolation for this.

The problem is that, I also want to be able to edit the name of the `belongs_to` objects, and I would like Paperclip to rename the files accordingly.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Make < ActiveRecord:Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :models
end

class Model < ActiveRecord:Base
  attr_accessible :img, :make, :name

  belongs_to :make
  has_attached_file :img, :style => { :thumb => "100x100" },
                    :path => "/cars/:make_name/:name/:style/:hash.png",
                    :hash_secret => "blabla"

  Paperclip.interpolates :make_name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.make.name
  end

  Paperclip.interpolates :name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.name
  end
end
```

So let's say I create a make `Chevrolet` and a Model `Camaro`, my image path will be `/cars/chevrolet/camaro/thumb/my_hash.png`

If I decide to change the `Chevrolet` entry name to `Chevy`, Rails try to locate the image at `/cars/chevy/camaro/thumb/my_hash.png`, but as the image was not renamed, it's not found.

How do I force Paperclip to update all the images paths when an entry is renamed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more robust file path could use the make id instead of make name. I.e., `/cars/:make_id/:name/:style/:hash.png` would continue to work when the make name is changed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: I can't do that, or I loose all existing data ... Ain't there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

I found several way around. Let me explain.

First I think this issue has occurred to many of us, and it would make sense to make it a default paperclip feature.

There are two solutions :

1. Move/rename the files to the new logic : cleaner, less CPU used (no image reprocessing), but more case by case (depending on the interpolation, local storage vs. S3 storage etc.) and risky (when having production server)

   Here are the answers when people decided to move files:

   - [Paperclip renaming files after they're saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708115/paperclip-renaming-files-after-theyre-saved)
2. Create a new, and destroy the former one. This is the one I chose.

So first, you need to intercept when the file logic is moving. In my case, I have a `before_save :generate_slug` method which regenerates the `slug` of a user if it changed. This is where I should put the paperclip regeneration logic since my `interpolation` contains `slug`.

The only hacky thing I had to do was to add `http://localhost:3000` to `user.avatar.url` because it returns the local path to the file when in local, instead of an `URI` which is used to do `URI.parse`. I use S3 in production, so in that case it works.

Here is my `generate_slug` method:

```
  def generate_slug
    if !(self.slug == self.fullname.parameterize) # Changed
      if self.avatar.exists? # There actually is an avatar to move
        if self.avatar.url.include? "http"
          avatar_url = self.avatar.url
        else # means url is local path ==> needs to add localhost to have a correct URI
          avatar_url = 'http://localhost:3000' + self.avatar.url
        end
        self.avatar.clear # To remove the former file
      end

      self.slug = self.fullname.parameterize

      if !avatar_url.blank?
        self.avatar = URI.parse(avatar_url)
      end
    end
  end
```

Hope it helps, wish there was a cleaner solution !