# Why are keys not being output after I add a symbol to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Why are keys not being output after I add a symbol to an array?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708115/paperclip-renaming-files-after-theyre-saved) about how to rename files in [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). As far as I understand the answer shows a symbol being added to the array so I have been experimenting in the rails console.

However, I ran into a problem; when I add the **:original** symbol to the array I can only see the output "original" and not the two keys.

The closest I have come to replicating the output I want is example 3 but that has required creating a separate variable and then going into a loop.

Why aren't the other two keys being output?

-------------Example 1----------------------------------------

```
Photo.first.attachment.styles.keys+[:original].each do |foo|
  puts foo
end


original
 => [:medium, :thumb, :original]
```

---

-----------Example 2-------------------------------------------

```
Photo.first.attachment.styles.keys.each do |foo|
  puts foo
end

medium
thumb
=> [:medium, :thumb]
```

---

----------Example 3--------------------------------------------

```
foo = Photo.first.attachment.styles.keys + [:original]

foo.each do |bar|
  puts bar
end

medium
thumb 
original
=> [:medium, :thumb, :original]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is *precedence*: instead of adding `:original` to `keys` and iterating, example 1 iterates, then adds.

Another way to enforce the right order is to use parenthesis:

```
(Photo.first.attachment.styles.keys + [:original]).each do |foo|
  puts foo
end
```