# Paperclip rename uploaded files by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Is it possible to allow the user to rename the uploaded file?

If there is a share link, will it be automatically updated. I am not able to do this since i cant first figure out how to rename the file.

Answer (score 8):

You can rename the files and then change the record file name. For instance, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708115/paperclip-renaming-files-after-theyre-saved) answer, you can do:

```
(record.image.styles.keys+[:original]).each do |style|
    path = record.image.path(style)
    FileUtils.move(path, File.join(File.dirname(path), new_file_name))
end

record.image_file_name = new_file_name
record.save
```

If you're using Amazon S3, you can do:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.move_to record.image.path(style), new_file_path, record.image.bucket_name
```

Check this out: [Paperclip renaming files after they're saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708115/paperclip-renaming-files-after-theyre-saved)

Comment: You could have given credit to @voyta : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708115/paperclip-renaming-files-after-theyre-saved ;)

Comment: My bad, I spoke too fast ... If you delete your comment I'll delete mine.